# How to use "document.querySelector" in Google Blogger?

Tags: css, blogger

The following code seems to be working just fine on a computer, but breaks in `Google Blogger`.

```html
<style>
  .box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline : 1px solid #f00;
  }
  .box p{
    color: blue;
  }
</style>

<div class="box">
  <p>This is test text.</p>
</div>
<script>
  var box = document.querySelector('.box');
  box.style.border = "5px solid red";
  box.style.outline = "30px solid blue";
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your selector is first class element

if all (.box)

use document.querySelectorAll(".box")
return all box elements in array

example

```js
  var box = [...document.querySelectorAll('.box')];
    
  
  box.forEach((el) => {
    el.style.border = "5px solid red";
    el.style.outline = "30px solid blue";
  })
```

```css
  .box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: 1px solid #f00;
    margin: 10px;
  }

  .box p {
    color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>This is test text.</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p>This is test text.</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p>This is test text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

in your blogger

Navigate to the Layout tab and click Add a Gadget ,select “HTML/JavaScript" ,create your js code and save it
you can follow this tutorial it will take you step by step:[a link](https://help.qualaroo.com/hc/en-us/articles/201696523-Installing-the-JavaScript-on-Blogger)